# From Beijing international airport to Great Wall of China at midnight

Tags: airport-transfer, china, beijing, great-wall-of-china

I arrive in Beijing international airport at 3:00 in the night. In order to catch the sunrise on Great Wall located near Yingbinsong and save more time I think it is a good idea to go directly to Great Wall from the airport. It is also nice, because the airport is located somewhere between Beijing and Great Wall. Is it possible to take a bus at midnight to this location? How much would it cost to go by taxi?

Since I'll visit Beijing twice, the second time I will land at 11:00 in the morning. Is it convenient to go directly to Great Wall from the airport or should I go to Beijing first?

Answer (score 7):

When you land at 3:00 AM, you should probably take taxi. It'll cost you around $55. (I've checked the rates over a site that i own, so i'm not sure if i should share the URL. Because i don't want to get marked as SPAM)

When you land at 11:00 AM, you should probably take the bus and following are the choices taken from http://www.beijing-airport-transportation.com/beijing-airport-to-great-wall-of-china.html

**Choice 1:** Take Bus No.359 and get off at Zuojiazhuang for the switch of Bus No.379, then get off at Xisanqi stop for the switch of Bus No. 919 to Badaling Great Wall.

**Choice 2:** Take Airport Express Train to Dongzhimen for the switch of Subway Line 2, then get off at Jishuitan Station, walk to Deshengmen and take Bus No. 919 to Badaling Great Wall.

**Choice 3:** Take Airport Shuttle Bus Line 5 to Baofusi Stop, then take Yuntong 109 to Xisanqi Stop, finally take Bus No. 919 to Badaling Great Wall.

I haven't been to China yet but i'm sure that a sunrise at Great Wall would be spectacular.

I hope it helps.

Comment: When you use the $ symbol, do you mean USD?

Answer (score 4):

Beijing airport shuttle starts from 5.30 AM,  and there will be no buses at that time. You will need to take a taxi.

I haven't been to the part of Great Wll you mentioned but I've been to Badaling and Mutiyanyu. Both are about half an hour from a bus, but again, you will have to take a taxi. Even with a bus, you will have to take 2 buses to go from Beijing (say, Tianmen East) to the Mutiyanyu, so your better chance is a taxi.

I doubt you will be able to view the very first scenes of the sunrise, specially since you have to take a ticket and booths usually open at 6.

Note that the sunrise in Beijing is usually at 5.30 AM. 
Also, there is a nice park just outside the Tianmen square, "Beihai" park, that many locals go to see the sun rise. 2 Yuan entry ticket. After the sun rise, you can even go back to the Tianmen square to see the flag raising ceremony.

Comment: 'Note that the sunrise in Beijing is usually at 5.30 AM.' That is not generally true, as this will vary on the season. Sunrise in Beijing is any time between [4:45](http://www.timeanddate.com/sun/china/beijing?month=6) in June  and [7:36](http://www.timeanddate.com/sun/china/beijing?month=12) in December.

Comment: Thanks @drat. OP didn't mention the dates of his visit so I just wrote what I experienced. Some parks open late in Winter season too, so we better take that into account.

Comment: I'll be in Beijing in June. But is it possible to get see wall at 5:30 in the morning. I suppose i will need to buy ticket?

Comment: Great wall? Yes you will need to buy a ticket (it usually costs about $30 with cable car + bus transfer + wall access). Even if you couldn't make it by the time, still give a try to climb to the top. It was beautiful even at 12PM. Have a ice trip!